# Email Alert for blank field in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation

In SharePoint List I need help on below points :-

1) Every week consolidated report mail should be trigger to user/Group for PO Number which Part No entry is blank.
Please advice,

[image]

Comment: I have deleted the old one and this is not duplicate, in my old post I posted both question in one thread and it was confusing. So I post both question in different thread. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Such tasks are usually done using SharePoint timer jobs or scheduled tasks. The code will get hold of the list and query the list to get the relevant items and mail the info to the users. See this for difference between two approaches:

[When should we use SharePoint Timer job and when Windows Task Scheduler?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96089/when-should-we-use-sharepoint-timer-job-and-when-windows-task-scheduler/96125#96125)

Comment: Thanks Nadeem, Here we have only access for SharePoint Designer. Can you please suggest if you have some steps or link to archive this.

Comment: You may have to do some research on workflows.